# VIP login/confirmation with multiple id's (Python)

Tags: python

I have made a Vip login system which validates the user's input by comparing it with saved data on a "customer.txt" file to find if they are a VIP member.

```
def vip_login():
    x = input("Enter your VIP member id: ")
    customer = open('customer.txt', 'r+')
    with open('customer.txt','r+') as fp:
        for line in fp.readlines():
            VIP_id, last_name, address, contact = line.split(":")
            if x == VIP_id:
                print ("Welcome back " + last_name +", "+ address)
            if x != VIP_id:
                print ("Invalid id")
                customer.close()
```

This code however only works for the inital person on this list:

```
1234:Jones:49 Arundel Road, Erina Heights, 2260:0412345678

2345:Smith:115 Long Street,Terrigal, 2260:0401234565

3456:MacDonald:89 Main Street, Wyoming, 2250:0419888324

4567:Monty:67 Serpentine Road, Somersby, 2250:0402234512

5678:Saint:134b Smithson Parade, Wamberal, 2260:0498342564

6789:Wiggles:10/14 Charles Kay Drive,Terrigal, 2260:0423123243
```

And even then, im greeted with "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 1)".
My question is how do i remove this ValueError, and apply this code to all id's so that they all can log in?

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you don't need to open the file. Once open the file, load all the data to a dictionary with the `vip_id` as the key and other details as the value. Then check whether input `id` is in the dictionary or not

```
all_vips = {}

with open('customer.txt','r+') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        if line.strip():
            VIP_id, last_name, address, contact = line.split(":")
            all_vips[VIP_id] = {
                "last_name" : last_name,
                "address": address,
                "contact": contact
            }

def vip_login():
    x = input("Enter your VIP member id: ")
    if x in VIP_id:
        print ("Welcome back " + all_vips[x]["last_name"] +", "+ all_vips[x]["address"])
    else:
        print ("Invalid id")

vip_login()
```

Comment: Applied this, seemed to be getting 3 out of 4 values now though

Comment: You should be getting all the values if you try for all

Comment: sorry, quite new to python, im still vexed at this error

Comment: VIP_id, last_name, address, contact = line.split(":")
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 4, got 3)

Comment: You get that because, some of the lines in your text file doesn't have enough data when you split the line by `:`. Put an if condition before splitting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218714/discussion-between-ando-and-bigbounty).